# Can not create 8051 project in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, sdcc

I'm using macOS. I have downloaded [sdcc for Mac](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sdcc/files/snapshot_builds/x86_64-apple-macosx/sdcc-snapshot-x86_64-apple-macosx-20220622-13535.tar.bz2/download) and installed it followed `INSTALL.txt` inside the downloaded folder (simply copy it to `Developer` folder), and have Eclipse IDE for Embedded C/C++ Developer installed. Then I installed [eclipseSDCC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-sdcc/) (I don't know if the plugin is platform specific). Seems everything in the right way.

However, when I new a project in Eclipse. I found the Toolchains is empty, so I can't create one. So, how can I deal with it?

[image]

Comment: To the one with the close request: I think this question is fine, since it asks about a problem with a tool commonly used by programmers.

Comment: What happens if you deselect "Show project types and toolchains only ..." at the bottom? -- As a Eclipse user since 15 years, and using it for many embedded control projects, I never knew that there is a SDCC specific plugin. Interesting, as I used SDCC a few times. However, I commonly use a Makefile project ("... with existing code..." even if it has no sources yet) and no toolchain selected. This way Eclipse is a convenient IDE, but does not get in my way with some underlying magic. -- I will bookmark this question. ;-)

Comment: @thebusybee Very appreciated! After I untick the option, the toolchain appeared but unable to click on "Finish" to create the project after selecting it. So I have the idea of taking your method (Makefile project...) into my workflow. But since I'm a beginner to this field, can you offer some detailed info? Like how can I load program into microcontroller after that (I have a dev board). Very appreciated :-)

Comment: Did you enter a project name? -- Uploading or flashing depends heavily on the specific MCU and the tools at hand. I add a special target for this in the Makefile and use the command line version of the appropriate tool. -- Use the "Build Targets" view to add all needed targets. You can even enter any command line for such a target. Learn about Make, optimally on the command line, for best experience in Eclipse. -- However, this site is not the place to teach beginners, it is a Q&A site. There are tons of other resources to read and learn.

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks. The disability of creating is because I forget to type the name. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Great! Now you might like to check my answer below, and if you like it, mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the prerequisites that renders a toolchain as "supported", these steps enables you to create an 8051 project:

- Specify a project name.
- Uncheck the checkbox at the bottom that reads "Show project types and toolchains only if they are supported on the platform".